# Combo Streak in a game how do you save them when resetting to 0

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Im making this game its kinda like dance dance revolution and I can quite figure out how to save the highest streak of a combo so the combo streak does well every time you hit an arrow Combo_Counter increment by 1 and if you miss 1 your Combo_Counter reset to 0 its all good but I want to save the highest combo streak and dont quite know what to do. Here is a sample of my code:

```
Combo_Count.Text = Combo_Counter
    Combo_Counter_2 = Combo_Counter
    If Combo_Counter >= 1 Then
        Combo.Visible = True
        Combo_Count.Visible = True
    End If
    If Combo_Counter = 0 Then
        Combo.Visible = False
        Combo_Count.Visible = False
    End If
```

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with a combobox (aka dropdown list)?  And what programming language is this?  VBA?

Comment: Not really but it requires a tag dont really know what to put so i selected combo box lol

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Visual Basic NET 2008

Comment: look at `My.Settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a highest_combo variable. When a combo ends, immediately before you reset the combo counter to 0, check if the current combo is greater than highest_combo. If so, set highest_combo equal to the current combo. Reset the current combo to zero after that.

Based on the code in your comment, I think you'd want something like this:

```
If RArrowDown.Top + RArrowDown.Height < ClientRectangle.Top Then
    TimerMain.Enabled = False
    RArrowDown.Visible = False
    TimerMain.Enabled = True
    Miss += 1

    If Combo_Counter > MaxCombo Then
        MaxCombo = Combo_Counter
    End If

    Combo_Counter = 0
    Misses.Visible = True
    TimerMiss.Enabled = True
End If
```

with ComboCounter set to zero when the game starts.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult - can you post the code which resets the combo counter to zero?

Comment: If RArrowDown.Top + RArrowDown.Height < ClientRectangle.Top Then
            TimerMain.Enabled = False
            RArrowDown.Visible = False
            TimerMain.Enabled = True
            Miss += 1
            Combo_Counter = 0
            Misses.Visible = True
            TimerMiss.Enabled = True
        End If

Comment: I've updated my answer with code along the lines of what probably needs to be done.